# Average function in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe shown below

[image]

A user supplies a value, I want to calculate the average of the second number in the tuple from all the rows above that particular value.

*example*: lets say the value is 10. I want to take all the rows whose value in the "value" column is greater or equal to 10 and calculate the average of those rows.  In this case, it'll take up the first two rows and the output will be as shown below
[image]

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Can you provide the schema of your data frame ?

Comment: StructField("year",IntegerType(), True),StructField("value1", IntegerType(), True)
The above is the initial schema. I then used a withColumn to create a "Tuple" and the "value" columns and dropped the original two columns.  The following is how I created the tuple
sorted_df.withColumn("tuple",struct(sorted_df.OccYear,sorted_df.value1))

Comment: what is your spark version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option: You can filter the data frame first and then calculate the average; Use `getItem` method to access the `value1` field in the struct column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.filter(df.value >= 10)
  .agg(f.avg(df.tuple.getItem('value1')).alias('Avg'), 
       f.lit(10).alias('value')
  ).show()

+------+-----+
|   Avg|value|
+------+-----+
|2200.0|   10|
+------+-----+
```